# Sharepoint Online Survey | Yes/No (checkbox) > Horizontal Alignment of Box and Text

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, survey

I am looking for the right approach to align the style of box and text. As of now, the question is shown on top and below comes the box. Taking a look at the underlying HTML, it looks like the two elements are separated into two rows of . The only thing I found and played with was the JSON Formatter, but unfortunately, I did not have any luck with this. Do you know a way how to make the two appear horizontally, i.e. next to each other? What would be the right approach? Thanks for any help!

EDIT | Screenshot and HTML added:

[image: This is how a question element looks:]

And this is what it looks like looking at the source code:

```
<tr>
   <td valign="top" width="90%" class="ms-formlabel">
      Scrum.org - PSD
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td valign="top" width="90%" class="ms-formbody">
      <!-- FieldName="Scrum.org - PSD"
         FieldInternalName="Scrum_x002e_org_x0020__x002d__x01"
         FieldType="SPFieldBoolean"
         -->
      <span dir="none">
      <input id="ctl00_ctl30_g_f1a31b94_6947_4f7f_a9fc_425781c5fb70_ctl00_ctl02_ctl06_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_BooleanField" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ctl30$g_f1a31b94_6947_4f7f_a9fc_425781c5fb70$ctl00$ctl02$ctl06$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$ctl00$BooleanField" /><br />
      </span>
   </td>
</tr>
```

As far as I am concerned, I do not know how to influence this representation.

Comment: Post the code and screenshots

Comment: @jpollar code and screenshot added

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you hide the default checkbox, create a new checkbox with js code after ‘Scrum.org-PSD’, synchronize the behaviour of the two checkboxes, and you can achieve the requirement.